# codeigniter sessions problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have biuld a shopping cart site using Codeigniter 1.7 with Cart class and session class for users handle. Site runs good on dev server but in production when I add a product to cart and I try to see the cart contains is empty also users cant log in.

The strange part site runs perffectly on Firefox 4.
My bet is something related with session but i am not sure

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: fixes with $config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue its almost also a naming issue with the product name or id.
if you check out `system/libraries/cart.php` you will see that it applies these rules:

```
var $product_id_rules = '\.a-z0-9_-'; // alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, or periods
var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9'; // alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, colons or periods
```

so I often had users entering a product named with Japanese characters or a copyright symbol... and it fails this check and wont add anything to the cart.

also check out the _insert() function in that same class.. it might help you.

.. also not sure about 1.7, but in 2.0 the cart fails to add if the price is 0 cos it removes leading zeros.. leaving an empty string.

But for all these, you should get something useful in your CI log file, if you turn it on.

Comment: I found what the problem was : the producciont server time was different I read on the CI forums that "Check the date and time on your server. If its too far off then some browsers will destroy the session because the server time is so far off."